# Displaying values in descending order doesn't work

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an app with Ionic and **Firebase**.

Now, I try to display posts by descending order : the newest to the oldest. Problem is, whatever I do as a manipulation to save the timestamp, it somehow **always** renders it from the oldest to the newest.

I tried :

1. By timestamp
2. By timestamp reversed (-1 * timestamp)
3. By substracting to a giant number (9999999999999999 + (-1 * timestamp)

**always** the same result.

**UPDATED:** And here is how I retrieve it :

```
  var myId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('/accounts/' + myId + '/discussions/');
    ref.orderByChild("timestamp").on("value", function(snapshot1) {
      this.data = [];
      snapshot1.forEach(function(child) {
      this.data.push(child.val());
    }.bind(this));

      $timeout(function(){
      $scope.discussions = this.data;

      })
    })
```

Any idea ?

Comment: It's probably order by a string. Datetime types are tricky when ordering. Is there a way to specify that the type is a Datetime or Timestamp?

Comment: Hello, tried it, gives it the same exact result. Whatever the order or the string or the date format too.

Comment: You'll need to loop over the snapshot's children as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883620/how-to-order-by-timestamp-using-firebase/37887160#37887160 (which christo8989 helpfully linked earlier). If you still have the same problem after that, update the code in your question.

Comment: Hello, I have just updated my original post to show you how I display it with this method and I still have the same result... I do not understand...

Comment: I don't see where you're making it descending at all.  Maybe I'm just missing it?  Is there a .reverse() somewhere that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: Hello Aaron, that's the point, I don't understand how to reverse it with that code !

Comment: Nevermind ! it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the **.reverse()** method worked !

Final code :

```
var myId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        var ref = firebase.database().ref('/accounts/' + myId + '/discussions/');
        ref.orderByChild("timestamp").on("value", function(snapshot1) {
          this.data = [];
          snapshot1.forEach(function(child) {
          this.data.push(child.val());
        }.bind(this));

          $timeout(function(){
          $scope.discussions = this.data.reverse() ;

          })
        })
```