# How to display data in the order of the time it is created with Firebase Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know it is something that is not very difficult but i am just starting with firebase. And my question is how can i display data in the order of time it is created using Firebase. Currently i am ordering by the name.

Here is how i write in my datebase and then display

```js
// displaying and deleting data

function renderCafe(doc) {
  let li = document.createElement('li')
  let name = document.createElement('name')
  let phone = document.createElement('phone')
  let specialist = document.createElement('specialist')
  let data = document.createElement('data')
  let cross = document.createElement('div')
  
  
  li.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id)
  name.textContent = doc.data().name;
  phone.textContent = doc.data().phone;
  specialist.textContent = doc.data().specialist;
  data.textContent = doc.data().data;
  cross.textContent = 'x';
  
  
  li.appendChild(name);
  li.appendChild(phone);
  li.appendChild(specialist);
  li.appendChild(data);
  li.appendChild(cross);
  
  

  doctorList.appendChild(li);

  //deleting data

  cross.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
    db.collection('patients').doc(id).delete();
  })
} 

  
  // real-time listener 
  const doctorList = document.querySelector('.patients');

  db.collection('patients').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.forEach(change => {
      if(change.type == 'added') {
        renderCafe(change.doc);
      } else if (change.type == 'removed') {
        let li = doctorList.querySelector('[data-id=' + change.doc.id +']');
        doctorList.removeChild(li);
      }
    })
  })
```

This is how i create to documents

```js
const createForm1 = document.querySelector('#patient');
createForm1.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  db.collection('patients').add({
    name: createForm1['name'].value,
    phone: createForm1['phone'].value,
    specialist: createForm1['specialist'].value,
    data: createForm1['date'].value
    
  }).then(() =>{

   //clear data
    document.getElementById('patient').reset();

    document.querySelector('.alert1').style.display='block';
        // Hide alert after 3 seconds
        setTimeout(function(){
        document.querySelector('.alert1').style.display='none';
        },3000);
  })
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to order by timestamp using Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883620/how-to-order-by-timestamp-using-firebase)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a [Server Timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp) in your `patients` documents (call it `timestamp`, for example), and then use it to sort your documents.

How it works: When you write `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` at some document property, it is replaced by a server timestamp (a number) in the database, so you can use it for sorting.

Edit: In the code you added, do something like this:

```
db.collection('patients').add({
  name: createForm1['name'].value,
  phone: createForm1['phone'].value,
  specialist: createForm1['specialist'].value,
  data: createForm1['date'].value,
  timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  // or timestamp: Date.now(), if you trust the client's clock
})
```

Comment: Thank you, i kind of uderstood it, but still not sure how to implement it in my code

Comment: @Nick show us your code that writes in the database so we can help you

Comment: @Nick That's not the code that writes in the DATABASE. It should be something like `db.collection('patients').add(patientObject)` or `db.collection('patients').doc(patientId).set(patientObject)`

Comment: @Stratubus it is in the end
 // real-time listener
  const doctorList = document.querySelector('.patients');

  db.collection('patients').onSnapshot(snapshot => {

Comment: @Nick this is how you read the database to update the UI. There should be some code that creates new documents, unless you created them by hand through the firebase console, or someone else's program creates them.

Comment: @Stratubus my bad, was reading between the lines. I just updated the post with the info.